# What happens when you apply a theme to an activity/application and style to a view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

I am new to android programming. I wanted to know, what would happen when you apply a theme to an application or activity as:

```
<application
android:theme="@style/MyTheme"...
```

and inside the activity one of the buttons has:

```
<Button
<style="@style/my_button_style"..
```

Would it pick the style defined in the my_button_style or the style defined in the theme? I experimented but the results are a bit confusing.

Comment: it would pick `my_button_style`

Answer (score 2):

This sets a theme for your entire application from the start:

```
<application
android:theme="@style/MyTheme"...
```

But explicitly applying a `style` to any of your elements in your xml like this will override the application `theme` set in your manifest ONLY for that specific element you applied `style` to.

```
<Button
<style="@style/my_button_style"..
```

In summary it's the last declaration that will win so since it goes like

**Manifest --> layouts**

then

**Manifest `android:theme="theme"` --> View element `style="@style/style"`**

so in the end your `style` declaration will override the `theme` but only for the element it's declared in.